# Vector labels in Python

Tags: python, numpy, vector, scikit-learn, bitwise-operators

I am studying from a machine learning book, and in a part of a code this appears:

```
X_train_01_subset= X_train [(y_train ==0) | (y_train ==1)]
y_train_01_subset= y_train [(y_train ==0) | (y_train ==1)]
```

`X_train` is a 104x2 vector with training samples, and `y_train` is a 104x1 vector and contains sample labels: 0,1 and 2.

What does

```
[(y_train ==0) | (y_train ==1)]
```

in  `X_train` and `y_train` do? (The algorithm is a bit extensive, if you need to put all the code, let me know)

Comment: Well Python doesn't have matrices either :-). No, please continue to use accurate language. But if you're using a major library like NumPy, please also tag your question with it. I'll fix this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breaking it in steps. First, this

```
(y_train == 0)
(y_train == 1)
```

is an operation to generate boolean mask.

Then, this:

```
(y_train ==0) | (y_train ==1)
```

is a *bitwise OR* operation. That is, it outputs `1` if either or both of the values is `1` else `0`.

Here is an example:

```
# inputs
In [22]: a = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0]) 
In [23]: b = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0]) 

# bitwise or
In [24]: a | b 
Out[24]: array([1, 1, 1, 0])
```

And, finally we use the above result as index to retrieve samples from `X_train`:

```
X_train [(y_train ==0) | (y_train ==1)]
```